# Windows Aero removes Title bar buttons in RibbonWindow

Tags: c#, wpf, ribbon

**Edit:** After some testing I have simplified the problem I am having. The issue here is that when in aero mode, the menubar buttons do not show up

I have an application that is being updated to include the Microsoft ribbon control.

Added References:
 `System.Windows.Controls.Ribbon`v.4.0.0.0 and `RibbonControlsLibrary` v.4.0.0.11019. The window has been converted from `Window` to `RibbonWindow`

The problem I am encountering is that when in aero mode the menu bar for the ribbon is showing up with a white background and the menu bar buttons (minimize, maximize and close) are missing.

Ribbon in non-Aero
[image]
Ribbon in Aero
[image]